# Azure Pipelines environments approvals

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

I have set up 2 environments and protected only one environment.

However pipeline run expect me to approve even before it starts.

I am assuming that Build and DevEnv deployment should happen un attended and **should stop for QAEnv** alone. Am I missing anything?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with Daniel Mann.

You could split the jobs into two stages (Dev stage and QA stage).

Here is an example:

```
stages:
- stage: Dev_Stage
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeployWeb
    displayName: deploy Web App
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu-latest'
    environment: 'env1'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - script: echo Hello world

- stage: QA_Stage
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeployWeb
    displayName: deploy Web App
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu-latest'
    environment: 'env2'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - script: echo Hello world
```

Result:

[image]

In this case, the stage1 has no check steps , the stage2 needs to be checked.

If you set the environment for the two stages separately, the two stages are independent of each other, they will not interfere with the other stage.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If there is an existing answer that correctly addresses the question, feel free to edit that question to include any clarifications or additional information that you feel is necessary. There is no need to create a second answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `dependsOn: <environment>` to your jobs. As it stands, it's trying to run all of the stages at once.

You also have all of those jobs within a single stage, which looks off to me.

You need to split them into multiple stages:

```
stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs: ...
- stage: DEV
  jobs: ...
- stage: QA
  jobs: ...
```

Comment: It did not work.  Gist link of pipeline https://gist.github.com/forvaidya/a1cb133007a7bb87710b266848c0981c

Comment: What does "did not work" mean? Did you get an error? You need to provide detail.

Comment: It did wait for approval for all 3 jobs basicBuild, onDevEnv and onQAEnv.  I expected that pipeline and onDevEnv will proceed without any intervention.

Comment: @forvaidya That's how you configured your approvals. If an environment has required approvals, it waits for the approval to be given before it proceeds.

Comment: Means in the chain of 3 environments (jobs) A->B->C if only C needs approval, whole chain will wait ?  just want to make sure.

Comment: Everything worked. github link for common good. https://github.com/forvaidya/azure-pipelines-env